# Does go compiler "squash" functions?

Tags: go, compilation, compiler-optimization

I am intrigued with a question that an engineer at the company I work at asked me, about whether or not it is better to have a single function that traverses an array and tests two conditions or to have two functions, with a single condition each.

I came here to ask you guys if my rationale is wrong or not.

The code was something near this:

```golang
response := ListObjectsFromS3(bucket)

var filteredEmptyObjectsArray = utils.FilterEmptyObjects(response)
var filteredNonJson = utils.FilterNonJson(filteredEmptyObjectsArray)
```

With each function being:

```golang
func FilterEmptyObjects(arrayToFilter []*Object) []*Object {
    var filteredArray []*Object
    for _, object := range arrayToFilter {
        if *object.Size > 0 {
            filteredArray = append(filteredArray, object)
        }
    }

    return filteredArray
}

func FilterNonJson(arrayToFilter []*Object) []*Object {
    var filteredArray []*Object
    for _, object := range arrayToFilter {
        if strings.HasSuffix(*object.Key, ".json") {
            filteredArray = append(filteredArray, object)
        }
    }
    return filteredArray
}
```

Please pardon the repetition in the code above. It is meant as a toy example.

I don't know exactly how does Go optimizes this code, but I was thinking it might "squash" both functions into something like this - of course, not in Go code but the generated machine code would be equivalent to this:

```golang
func FilterSquashed(arrayToFilter []*Object) []*Object {
    var filteredArray []*Object
    for _, object := range arrayToFilter {
        if strings.HasSuffix(*object.Key, ".json") && *object.Size > 0 {
            filteredArray = append(filteredArray, object)
        }
    }
    return filteredArray
}
```

And the code of the response - also not really in Go code, but the compiler would generate a machine code equivalent to something like this:

```golang
response := utils.FilterSquashed(ListObjectsFromS3(bucket))
```

The point is that when I made the objdump of the optimized code and the non-optimized one, both had the functions separated and would have a `CALL` to each function. So, I'm trying to understand what is the depth of optimization that is currently possible or that Go compiler decided to stick with.

Let me know your thoughts

Comment: This isn't an optimization of the kind a compiler cares about; the resulting code is no more efficient. This is just a refactoring.

Comment: Hey @Adrian, thanks a lot for the comment. The original code would traverse the array twice, whereas the squashed would only once. I'm wondering what you meant as "no more efficient" - you mean as in complexity?

Comment: There are multiple Go compilers. Whether one, or any, performs the type of optimization you're talking about, is an implementation detail, and not part of the spec, and thus not part of "Go".  If you're curious about the optimizations performed by a specific version of a specific compiler, that may be answered, but you'll need to specify.

Comment: The number of logical leaps that would be required of the optimizer to do what you're describing are far beyond what any compiler does today. Maybe one day we'll have some kind of AI-driven super-optimizer, but in the mean time, optimizations of this kind are still the responsibility of software engineers.

Answer (score 2):

The "squashed" code you show is not equivalent to the original code. The basic rule of code optimization is that the effects of the optimized and non-optimized code must be the same but in your example, you have two functions that apply different logic to filter a list, and a third function that would apply a third kind of logic that in this particular case would give you the composition of the two original functions, but not in the general case. So in short: no compiler would do what you are asking for in this case, because the semantics are different.

There may be cases when some functions are inlined the compiler might discover more optimizations, but I don't see how your example might benefit from inlining.

Comment: I was thinking if the compiler would be able to identify these restricted cases in which these squashes could be performed. What do you think?

Comment: I am not aware of any compiler optimizations that would do this. The only optimization in such restricted cases would be through inlining. It is unlikely that a compiler would try to identify if two separate non-trivial for-loops are identical, at least, I am not aware of any optimizations that would do this.